# Can I perform a query that returns data only for columns that match a wildcard?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I have a table `MyTable` with many columns, but the names of those columns have a pattern, like:

```
`BLOCK_A_PARAM_1` INT,
`BLOCK_A_PARAM_2` INT,
`BLOCK_A_PARAM_3` INT,
`BLOCK_A_PARAM_4` INT,
--- ...
`BLOCK_A_PARAM_25` INT,
`BLOCK_A_PARAM_26` INT,
`BLOCK_B_PARAM_1` INT,
`BLOCK_B_PARAM_2` INT,
`BLOCK_B_PARAM_2` INT,
--- ...
```

This data is not spread across multiple tables for a handful of reasons. My table doesn't suffer from a lack of normalisation *per se*, though this task would be easier if each block lived in a different table. Regardless, here I am.

**If I wanted to construct a query to return data only for columns whose names match `BLOCK_A_%`, how could I do it?**

This is only for utility during development, and would never be part of my application's logic.

---

I already tried:

```
SELECT (SHOW COLUMNS FROM `MyTable`
        WHERE `Field` LIKE "BLOCK_A_%") FROM `MyTable`;
```

but the resulting error indicates that `SHOW COLUMNS` as a subquery is invalid syntax.

---

This second attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
               WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = "MyTable"
               AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE "BLOCK_A_%") `_`;
```

simply lists the table schema details (i.e. the outer query is totally useless).

---

And, finally:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
        WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = "MyTable"
        AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE "BLOCK_A_%")
FROM `MyTable`;
```

but this results in the following error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

---

So, is there a way to do this? *In MySQL, please*; don't give me any PHP/ASP.NET/etc!

Comment: @Strawberry: Changing the layout of a database is not "the way" if the goal is a hack for making my life a little quicker during development ;)

Comment: @Strawberry: Plenty of other fields and tables in my database make use of relational logic, just not these ones. Other than this utility-of-inspection element, there is nothing about them that would benefit from splitting them up into multiple tables. There is no many-to-one, many-to-many relationship implied with any of them. All I'd be doing is making my application code more complicated than it needs to be. This question is purely a technical one: at a semantic level, there is no particular relationship between all my `BLOCK_A_%` fields, that would warrant design consideration.

Comment: Using a RDBMS doesn't mean everything _has_ to be in its own table for no reason.

Comment: @Strawberry: "Self-promotion"? Why do you say that? Are you aware that self-answering is not only permitted, but _encouraged_? That there is a button for it on the "Ask Question" page? It's about sharing knowledge! I found the solution below earlier today, and decided to share it with the world, for free.

Comment: @Strawberry: No, the answer was posted _simultaneously_ to the question: that is, the timestamps are identical. Please refer to my previous comment, and [this blog post from the founders of Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I have indeed posted several self-answered questions. Thank you.

Comment: Cool. (the way IS normalization, though ;-) )

Comment: @Strawberry: This is a fairly contrived example in order to present the general technique, but the wildcard pattern may not be as simple as a common prefix, and it may vary wildly depending on what I'm trying to debug. The resulting assortment of potential groupings will almost always have next to nothing to do with any particular logical arrangement of the data itself. :) One day I might want to observe `BLOCK_A_%`, and on another day `%_PARAM_1`; I'm certainly not going to re-arrange my schema for each of these debug tasks, nor would it be appropriate to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using prepared statements, you can build the query dynamically from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, then execute it:

```
SET @QUERY=CONCAT_WS(" ",
   "SELECT",
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME`) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
     WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = "MyTable" AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE "BLOCK_A_%"),
  "FROM `MyTable`");
PREPARE myQuery FROM @QUERY;
EXECUTE myQuery;
```